# Hide element if Radio-Button is checked

Tags: jquery, css

How do I hide the parent element `variant--group` if one of the radio buttons `option--input` is checked ?

This should work on pageload and on input change.

```css
.variant--group.is--disabled{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="variant--group">
<h3 class="variant--name">Format</h3>
<div class="variant--option">
<input type="radio" class="option--input" id="radio1" name="radio" value="">
<label for="radio1">radio1</label>
</div>
<div class="variant--option">
<input type="radio" class="option--input" id="radio2" name="radio" value="">
<label for="radio2">radio2</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide the closest variant-group

```
$("input[name= radio]:radio").change(function() {
    $(this).closest(".variant--group").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery function `.parents()` to identify and hide the container.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.option--input').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).parents('.variant--group').hide();
    }
    // not checked
  });
});
```

```css
.variant--group.is--disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="variant--group">
  <h3 class="variant--name">Format</h3>
  <div class="variant--option">
    <input type="radio" class="option--input" id="radio1" name="radio" value="">
    <label for="radio1">radio1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="variant--option">
    <input type="radio" class="option--input" id="radio2" name="radio" value="">
    <label for="radio2">radio2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```